# Multiple <html> blocks in a single file?

Tags: html

I'm working on a web project, and I was wondering if I could format a webpage by placing two (or more) html blocks one after another. Does this cause any side-effects? Will it potentially cause problems on mobile? Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible every document has only one HTML tag, and my question is why do you need that anyway?

Comment: Browsers are written to be forgiving with HTML, so you won't get exceptions popping up if you do this - but the HTML tag is supposed to be the root element of any HTML document. Most likely you won't get the desired result (not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this????)

Comment: it'll likely cause issues with JS and other things for the reason @RyanPierceWilliams mentioned. im so curious why do u wan do thiis????

Comment: However, you can include several files into one with frames: https://html.com/frames/
This may be handy for collage of online cameras, or status controlling, or... So the main question is probably `what for are you want to have several HTML tags?`.

Comment: This is possible. Would be an exception though; to work properly, either the document or the parser would have to breach the consensus html standard. Who to blame depending on your level of interest. On the bright side though, this technology update would allow intuitive design of strange but resource efficient document-as-network or file-in-file html document compositing. Great for purely serverless/ headless modern web(sic) apps.

Answer (score 2):

The *<html>* tag tells the browser that this is an HTML document.
The *<html>* tag represents the root of an HTML document.
The *<html>* tag is the container for all other HTML elements (except for the <!DOCTYPE> tag).
Therefore, having multiple ***<html>*** tags leads to ambiguity which eventually makes HTML document invalid.

Answer (score -1):

No you should not have more than one HTML tag in your file. With multiple tags it becomes an invalid document and will often times not display properly.

Note: You should only have one body tag as well. It is best practice to make each new page a new HTML file, but have all CSS on one file separate from the HTML.

Comment: The number of files really depends upon the complexity of the website. It is not uncommon to have multiple source files for both the HTML and for the CSS. More complex websites will dynamically construct pages on the server side.